# C# send table cell data from one page to another

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have two pages customer.aspx and customer_detail.aspc, each with their corresponding code behind files. The objective is being able to send a particular table cells's value from customer to customer_detail. For example, the following javascript renders the table dynamically onto customer.aspx based on the BindTable method in customer.aspx.cs file.
customer.aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "customer.aspx/BindCustomer",
                data: "{}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                        $("#customer_table").append("<tr><td>"+'<a id = "anchor" href="customer_individual.aspx">' + data.d[i].customer_name +'</a>'+ "</td><td>" + data.d[i].customer_id +"</td><td>" + data.d[i].total_value + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].created_date + "</td></tr>");
                    }
                },
                error: function(result) {
                alert("Error");
                }
            });
        });
```

The BindCustomer function above is a WebMethod written in customer.aspx.cs, which returns a customer array object, customer[], which is bound to the customer_table. Notice that, in the above I have a href within the first td element of the table, which redirects the page to the customer_detail.aspx.

The objective is to be able to send say a customer_name value upon clicking the link to the customer_detail.aspx.cs, so that I can query the customer object which I store separately, with the name and populate the page accordingly. What would be the best method to accomplish this? Any suggestions as to how to proceed will be greatly helpful!

Comment: When you say, 'send data to' a page, do you mean redirect the user to that page and display or somehow reference that data?

Comment: Yes, the link at the moment works wherein the 'customer_detail' page contains some static fields such as textboxes and labels. The user needs to be redirected to the page along with the value, data.d[i].customer_name, which I could then use to fill up a textbox on the customer_detail page

Comment: Then that's really all there is to it. Just append the value you want to pass to the url in the querystring.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to format a link to customer_detail.aspx with the data you want to pass in the querystring like this (it looks very similar to what you're already doing.)

```
<a href="/customer_detail.aspx?customerName=dataYouWantToPass">Link</a>
```

When customer_detail.aspx loads, you retrieve the value from the querystring.

In your `Page_Load` event in customer_detail.aspx

```
var customerName = Request["customerName"];
```

You could be more particular and say `Request.Querystring["customerName"]` but on this page you probably don't care whether the value was passed in the querystring or a form field. `Request["customerName"]` covers both.

Comment: Got it..i am trying this method out. Would the same thing be applicable to pass a deduced value? I mean i would like to pass in say, the dynamic value of data.d[i].customer_name, that is created during the creation of the data table at customer.aspx. In particular, would this be applicable?
   <a href="/customer_detail.aspx?customerName=data.d[i].customer_name">Link</a>, where the value of the Link above is data.d[i].customer_name

Comment: Hannan:Able to pass static text using the method suggested above and am able to retrieve this on the second page. . Can you suggest how I am able to retrieve this dynamic text? I tried the following: Modfying the href as: $("#patient_table").append("<tr><td>" + '<a href="patients_individual.aspx?patientName=">' + data.d[i].patient_name + '</a>' + "</td><td>" + "</td></tr>"); and within the same document.ready: $("a").prop("href", function () { return this.href += $.trim($(this).text());  }); I tried inlining too: onclick="window.location.href = this.href + $.trim($(this).text());
Suggestions?

Comment: You can't pass a function like that - just a static value. But it's better that way. Customer_detail.aspx doesn't need to know about where the parameter came from. It just has its input (the parameter) and does its thing.